# Which file has the Eclipse help menu contents

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to add my own sub menu option under the help menu of Eclipse SDK. Which file has the menu and submenu details.

Comment: Do you want to build a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to extend Eclipse with a new plug-in, when you create a new "Plug-in Project" in Eclipse, this new project contains a file named `plugin.xml`.

This file can be used to define the extensions that the plug-in will add to Eclipse.

More information on this can be found in the following references:

- [Introduction to Eclipse Plugin Development](http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/index.html)
- [Extending Eclipse - Plug-in Development Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html)
- [Contributing Actions to the Eclipse Workbench](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html)

Regarding the menus themselves and their possible extensions, you can read the Eclipse documentation [here](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_menus.html).

I hope this helps.